# How to translate "feature" in "Is it a feature or a bug"?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico, informática

How do you translate *feature* in "Is it a feature or a bug" or "That's a feature, not a bug"?

*Bug* could be *defecto*.  But I don't know what to do with *feature*.  The closest I've gotten is *cualidad* -- which doesn't quite work.

I'm open to a reworking of the whole sentence.

I would like to use these phrases in general conversation, not just in a software context.

---

Examples from outside the software world.

1. [How to Build Your Business Your Way](http://www.harperspero.com/blog/2017/9/17/how-to-build-your-business-your-way):

> My ability and determination to think creatively makes me a better coach and entrepreneur. And now that I’ve built a business my way, it’s a feature, not a bug.

2. [Yet Another Report About Voter Fears & Voting System Integrity](https://trustthevote.org/author/gam1357/)

Statement:

> The primary problem with the antiquated methods come down to a single fundamental issue, centralization.

Response:

> Well, actually, that centralization is necessary and it isn’t central, but local — the machinery of U.S. elections are [sic] required to be in the control of U.S. local election officials.  It’s a feature not a bug.

3. On the MIR Space Station, something was constantly breaking down.  The astronauts stationed at MIR were constantly having to fix one thing or another just so the station could stay afloat.  The silver lining of that was that the astronauts didn't have time to get depressed.  A cynic might say that the decrepitude of MIR turned out to be a feature, not a bug.

---

What I plan to say in future (bottom line):

> Es parte de la funcionalidad, no un fallo de diseño.

Comment: Cómo usarías esto en otros contextos que no sean informática? Puedes dar ejemplos por favor?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yo lo traduciría como

> Es esto parte de la **funcionalidad** (de la aplicación) o es un *bug*?
>
> Eso es parte de la **funcionalidad** de la aplicación, no un *bug*.

Todos usamos `bug` en español en el context de la informática. Creo que intentar traducirlo como "defecto" o "error" es innecesario. Este anglicismo está ampliamente aceptado en la industria.

Comment: Also  just "función", I think.

Comment: @diego - Pero ¿fuera de la industria? // "Feature story": creo que esta frase se refiere a un artículo de primera plana, ¿no?  Entonces no entiendo "historia de funcionalidad."

Comment: @aparente001, cierto, pero de ahí los tags, si no esto sería demasiado amplio. Al decir "feature or bugs", creo que se puede asumir que el contexto es programación. "Feature article" (o feature story) podría ser en periodismo un artículo de primera plana, artículo (o historia) destacadas e incluso un reportaje especial. `Feature` se puede traducir de muchas maneras distintas dependiendo de la industria. Incluso con los edits de tu pregunta mantengo mi respuesta, pues creo que "feature or bug" es una especie de modismo sacado del ámbito de la informática y yo optaría por traducirlo como explico

Comment: @Diego - Bien, gracias.  Entonces, si quiero comentar lo equivalente de "That's a feature, not a bug" en español, *fuera* del ámbito de la programación, en conversación normal, ¿todavía puedo decir "Eso es parte de la funcionalidad, no un bug"?  ¿Puedo decir *defecto* en lugar de *bug*?  Quizás la persona no va a entender bug... y no lo encontré en el DRAE.  (¿Por cierto, cómo se pronuncia DRAE?)

Comment: Recomiendo que quites tu último párrafo porque no viene al caso.

Answer (score 6):

The most common is "característica". Also "propiedad" fits.

As for "bug", it's usually translated as "fallo", but actually people tend to preserve the English word "bug".

Comment: "Bug" -- does it work outside a software context?  Is there a standard *frase hecha* for "This is a feature, not a bug" or "Is this a feature or a bug"?

Comment: Not really, it is only used for software context.

Answer (score 0):

En el mundillo informático de los años 70 del siglo pasado (que viejo me siento) se comentaba que ante un error detectado en el software del equipo de un grande de la época alguien, de marketing supongo, sugirió: 'this is not a bug, it's a feature'. Y así se quedo, no era un **fallo**, era una **característica**.

Comment: Gracias.  Me gusta más "parte de la funcionalidad" porque va más de acuerdo con lo positivo de *feature*.  *Característica* se oye más neutro que *feature*.